# Why does pandas `loc` throw `KeyError` with column name?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that is given this initial construct:

```
df_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['name','date','c1','c2']).set_index(['name','date'])
```

I then have code to fill this frame from a data base.  I can print some or all of the frame and get a sensible result.  Something like:

```
print df_data.c1.head(3)

name date
Joe  2019-01-01 234324
     2019-01-02 4565
     2019-01-03 573
Name: c1, dtype: object
```

After filling from the data base, I have various analysis calculations that try to access the data using `loc` as, for example, `df_data.loc['Joe', 'c1']`  I expect to get a result from from that with date for an index and the values of column `c1`, where the "name" part of the multiindex has been selected down to 'Joe'.  Something like:

```
print df_data.loc['Joe', 'c1']

date
2019-01-01 234324
2019-01-02 4565
2019-01-03 573
Name: c1, type: object
```

I've run this three times, filling the frame with different ranges of date.  Two of the three work as expected and described above.  In the third, I get `KeyError: ('Joe', 'c1')` for `df_data.loc['Joe', 'c1']` but, even in this "broken" case, I get a perfectly nice result for `df_data.loc['Joe'].c1`, which I think should give the same answer in this case.  I can also print the entire frame `df_data` and get a perfectly sensible result.  I interpret the `KeyError` here to mean that Pandas thinks that `c1` should be in the index rather than it giving a column name.

I cannot reproduce this in a stand-alone example as, for reasons I cannot understand, the result seems to depend on the data in the frame rather than structure of the frame. (Same structure "works" for two of three cases.)  So specific questions:

- Why or under what circumstances would the syntax `loc['Joe', 'c1']` cause `c1` to be treated as part of the key instead of a column name? (Whatever other error I may have, I don't see where the second argument here should be interpreted as part of the key under any documented scenario, e.g. I do *not* have something like `loc[('Joe','c1')]`.)
- Are there known or documented cases where something about the data in the frame could cause such a change in how the data access call is interpreted?

Comment: great question. I don't have an answer but I think that if you inspect the contents of `df_data.index` on your 3 scenarios might give some useful insights

Comment: Thanks, @Yuca.  The actual frames are quite large, so that puts out a lot of data.  Nothing immediately jumped as different in structure, but I will look again in more detail later.

Comment: Have you tried df_data.loc[['Joe', 'c1']] ? (double brackets)

Answer (score 1):

Use tuple notation: `df_data.loc[('Joe', 'c1')]`. See: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index

Comment: As noted, I tried this and it does something different.